# ng-repeat="thread in threads | orderBy:'-last_ts' | filter : globalSearch track by $index" tell me xpath for this NG repeat element

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

```
<div ng-click="changeChatThread(thread, true)" class="item ui three column grid thread_item ng-scope active-thread" ng-class="{'active-thread' : selectedThread === thread.chat_id}" ng-repeat="thread in threads | orderBy:'-last_ts' | filter : globalSearch track by $index">
      <div class="three wide column thread_image">
        <div class="ui tiny image">
          <img ng-src="img/avatar.png" src="img/avatar.png">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="three wide column thread_meta">
        <div class="ui label ng-hide" ng-show="thread.count > 0">
          <p class="ng-binding">0</p>
        </div>
        <div class="thread_attachment_icon ng-hide" ng-show="thread.last_message.attachments.length">
          <img ng-src="img/mainbox/assets/Attachment Icon.png" class="message_attachment" src="img/mainbox/assets/Attachment Icon.png">
        </div>
        <div class="thread_last_ts">
          <p ng-hide="thread.typing_message.length" class="ng-binding">6:29 PM</p>
          <p class="typing_message ng-binding ng-hide" ng-show="thread.typing_message.length"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

i want to get Xpath of through ng repeat element .
please help me for this

Comment: .//div[contains(@ng-repeat,'thread in threads')] this xpath will work.

Comment: Why you need xpath? you can directly use `element.all(by.repeater())`. if you still need to use xpath then kindly mention the problem that you are facing.

Comment: thanks for reply  ...i am facing so many problems in protractor so i need x path for this element <div ng-click="changeChatThread(thread, true)" class="item ui three column grid thread_item ng-scope active-thread" ng-class="{'active-thread' : selectedThread === thread.chat_id}" ng-repeat="thread in threads | orderBy:'-last_ts' | filter : globalSearch track by $index">

Comment: @SureshSalloju thanku so much

Comment: @VandanaJamnal is it working or not?

Comment: its working :) @SureshSalloju

Comment: If my solution works. I can post it as Answer.

Comment: its working in my script u can post it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would use the [`by.exactRepeater()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.exactRepeater) locator, it would drop all the extended repeater syntax part - the sorting, filters and indexing, so that you can simply do:

```
element.all(by.exactRepeater("thread in threads"));
```